# Cant get value from column when the value is 0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Take a look a this section of a table in my database:
[image]

The PrevOpNum column is there incase an Op gets inserted, but anyway I want to be able to take a $JobCardNum and $OpNum pair (which uniquely identifies a row in this table), and find out whether the previous Op has been started.
To do so I created this function:

```
public function scopePrevOpStarted($query, $JobCardNum, $OpNum)
{
    $PrevOpNum = $this::GetOp($JobCardNum, $OpNum)->value('PrevOpNum');

    return $query->GetOp($JobCardNum, $PrevOpNum)->value('OpStarted');
}
```

which is inside my 'JobCardOp' model. In my controller, If I do

```
return JobCardOp::prevOpStarted(3244, 50);
```

I get '1' returned, as expected. But if I do

```
return JobCardOp::prevOpStarted(3244, 40);
```

I get this error:

> ErrorException in Response.php line 396:
>       Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Trying other values I have deduced that I get an error when the previous Op has a 0 for the OpStarted column, but it works for a 1. Why is this happening? The type of OpStarted in TINYINT.

**UPDATE**

If do this:

```
public function scopePrevOpNum($query, $JobCardNum, $OpNum)
{
    return $query->GetOp($JobCardNum, $OpNum)->value('PrevOpNum');
}
```

and then this

```
return JobCardOp::GetOp($JobCardNum, prevOpNum($JobCardNum, $OpNum))->value('OpStarted');
```

It works. So who knows whats happening?

Comment: Please put your model code to trace down the issue